# Firefox bootstrapped extension, race conditions when importing in top-level?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, race-condition

I'm trying to get myself familiar with Firefox bootstrapped add-ons. Consider following example:

```
// bootstrap.js

'use strict'

function alert(message) {
    var prompts = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
    prompts.alert(null, "from my extension", message);
}

try {
    Components.utils.import('chrome://my-ext/content/foo.jsm');
    alert('ok');
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

And `chrome://my-ext/content/foo.jsm` being just `this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [];`.

The issue with an above code sample is that it does not work each time. It may fail with `NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` instead of importing, or may say OK — despite the fact later, when browser starts, I can access `foo.jsm` through location bar.

Does this mean I should not import anything in the top level, because chrome registration might not be done yet, or problem is in something else?

Comment: Awesome research there man. I did notice though with bootstrap addons that you can only import custom modules in the startup, I THINK, im not sure, this was my little foray into it: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** The following is my experience and may not be definite

bootstrap.js of bootstrapped addon run when browser starts and BEFORE any WINDOW or DOM is created.

bootstrap.js also has a order and specific format for execution.

Is above example the way your bootstrap.js is?

You can import Firefox modules anywhere (although I would always do so on top).

It is best to execute your `Components.utils.import('chrome://my-ext/content/foo.jsm');` within `function startup(data, reason) { ... }`

Additional Notes/Suggestions:

Generally, I would assign `var prompts` outside a function so that it is not reassigned every time a function is run. 
I would also use `Services.jsm` for ease of use (but it make no difference at all) eg:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

// then anywhere in the code
Services.prompt.alert(null, title, text);
```

Habitually, I do all **Firefox built-in modules** imports `Components.utils.import()` on top of the JS/JSM
**Firefox built-in modules**  (not addon's modules) are cached by Firefox and there is no need to `Components.utils.unload()` them.

Comment: Nice suggestions, but frankly saying I do not intend to use `alarm` function at all — I prefer logging to browser console (not that Firebug shows, but Tools - Web Developer - Browser console), alert is too alarming. However, it's perfect for alert-debugging, because message is seen immediately, so I just wanted to keep all the stuff inside so when time comes I won't need to search for alert implementation traces everywhere.

Comment: And yes, the above example is the whole `bootstrap.js`, I intentionally left out entry functions to demonstrate the concept. Imports will work in `startup()`, but they won't (sometimes) in `install()`, as they won't (again, sometimes) in the top level of `bootstrap.js` — when talking about generic `jsm`, they, of course, will, because it's assumed at the moment of importing `jsm` chrome registration is already done.

Comment: So, basically, all the troubles start when you try to bring modular approach to bootstrap process — I wanted to keep bootstrap.js small and tidy, only delegating all needed work to CoffeeScript file with same exports. Unfortunately, you can only import files by their absolute file path, and you still cannot import modules at the top of newly loaded `jsm` — you have to wrap imports in kind of `getImports()`, and then destructure it each time `startup()` or `shutdown()` called. Lame :(

Comment: @modchan I do the same... I have a tiny bootstrap.js and handle everything else in the imported module. However, the bootstrap.js MUST have a certain structure as mentioned. install() and uninstall() are used for a different thing. 99% of the code in handled via startup() & shutdown()

Comment: No, it must not. It's so called "structure" is formed after evaluating the script in a sandbox and then looking for `startup`, `shutdown`, `install` and `uninstall` symbols in sandbox' global context. It's no difference if these functions are defined explicitly via `function startup` or via `eval("this.startup = new Function()")`. If you are doing it the same way I originally intended, how do you come around missing chrome in `install()`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to `Cu.unload` @erosman? I thought if you import your own modules you have to unload them. Also I wasn't able to get importing of my own modules to work if i put them at top, it would only work if I put them in startup i couldnt explain that. Do you know why? It looks like you got your custom imports working outside of before `startup` runs?

Comment: @Noitidart .. I said "Firefox module imports" do not require unload. If you import your own modules, then they have to be unloaded. :)

Comment: @modchan .. I am not 100% sure what your actual code looks like. On the other hand, I am not an expert on how bootstrapped addon are processed by Firefox. What I have said, were based on my own experience :)

Comment: Re: "Firefox module imports": I would suggest making it more clear in the answer that you are specifically meaning modules which are in the Firefox distribution, not those in your add-on.  I also read the text in the answer as implying that you did not need to unload your own JSMs (which is obviously not the case, as you very specifically should unload them when the add-on is being disabled, removed, updated, etc., but there is no need on Firefox shutdown).